# Conditional pageref for labels that are in another section and on a page far away

Tags: cleveref, varioref, ref

Currently I am experimenting with the `cleverref` and the `varioref` package. These packages are great, however, I would like to have a reference command with the following subtle behavior:

- If the label and the reference are in *the same section*, then I would like to have the behavior of `\cref`.
- If the label and the reference are in *different sections*, then I would like to have the behavior of `\vref`.

The goal is to output a pageref only if the referenced label is in another section and on a page far away. The `\vref` command already solves the second condition (far away page) sufficiently, however, it does not consider the sections.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any reference to being "on a page far away" (as in the title).

Comment: @Werner: Sorry, this was only implicit in the `\vref` command. I tried to state may goal more clearly.